# CSS subclasses, am I doing it right?

Tags: css, subclass

```
.popUp
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
.question .popUp
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to make the question class a subclass of the popUp class. From what I googled this should work, but it doesn't. If I do this instead:

```
.question
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

It works, but that misses the point.

Comment: .question .popUp will target any child elements of the element that has .quetion...

Are you maybe looking for .question.popUp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`popup` class is `parent` container then you should select it as below.

```
.popUp .question
```

so syntax would be `parent space child`

Answer (score 3):

Keep the common styles in the base class, then add specific/overridden properties in the subclass.

```
.popUp
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}

.popUp-question
{
    /*width: 300px; This can move to parent */
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<div class="popUp popUp-question"></div>
```

Take a look at the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts) which demonstrates the use of subclasses in many components.  Their conventions seems to be to include the base class name in the subclass.  For example, base class `alert` and subclass `alert-success`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around, the container must come before the contained element in the definition:

```
.popUp .question
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.popUp .question {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both container1 and container2 have **subclass** "item" like shown below:

```
<div class=container1">
    <div class="item">Item1</div>
    <div class="item">Item2</div>
</div>

<div class=container2">
    <div class="item">Item1</div>
    <div class="item">Item2</div>
</div>
```

You can actually target the subclass in **CSS**.

```
.container1 .item {
    color: green;
}

.container2 .item {
    color: blue;
}
```